# split and strip elements in list python

Tags: python, file, list, strip

words is a list which look something like this:

```
        ['34 ', '111110 ', '0 ', '@jjuueellzz down ']
        ['67 ', '111112 ', '1 ', 'Musical awareness ']
        ['78 ', '111114 ', '1 ', 'On Radio786 ']
        ['09 ', '111116 ', '0 ', 'Kapan sih lo ']
```

If you notice there is a space at the end after every element in the list, I know I should strip but do not know how would I do that.
Here is my code:

```
words = line.split('\t')
```

If I do `words = line.strip().split('\t')` - it does not strip properly like I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to replace your first line with something like this:

```
words = [x.strip() for x in line.split('\t')]
```

This is a list comprehension, taking each element of the list returned by `line.split('\t')`, stripping it, and adding it to a new list.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest with a list comprehension:

```
lst = ['34 ', '111110 ', '0 ', '@jjuueellzz down ']
new_lst = [x.strip() for x in lst]
```

Now I'm not sure that I completely understand your input -- Perhaps you have a list of lists.  If that's the case, then you just put one list comprehension inside another:

```
new_data = [[x.strip() for x in lst] for lst in old_data]
```

---

If the original list is the result of `line.split('\t')`, the answer becomes even easier.  Split on any whitespace, not just tabs:

```
line.split()  # splits on *any* whitespace!.
```